# Java - Unit test cases for delegating class

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have a service class MyBusinessService with 2 methods doABC() and doXYX(). Method doABC() delegates the work to ABCHandler.do() and method doXYX() delegates the work to XYZHandler.do(). MyBusinessService class methods just delegates the works to corresponding handlers.

I have a question here. When i write Unit test for this, i must write unit tests for the methods in the handlers. Should i write UT for MyBusinessService class methods. I ask this question for 2 reasons.

a. With UT tests, one functionality should not be tested in 2 places. My actual logic is in handler classes and i should not unit test the same logic in both handler class and service class

b. If i dont write unit test for MyBusinessService class methods, then in the future if some developer makes some bug fix and breaks something, then it may cause the application to fail in production. So, i need a test here. But if i write test case for this class, this will break rule (a).

Please let me know whether i should write UT for delegating class(MyBusinessService class) or should i leave it to Integration test cases to address it.

Comment: Use a spy or a mock (see `Mockito.spy()` or `Mockito.mock()` for example) and test for proper delegation?

Comment: Where did you get rule a? In my opinion always err on the side of too much testing rather than not enough. If that means duplicating some tests then so be it.

Comment: @RC, I want to know whether its really needed to write UT for verifying delegation? Because it will automatically get verified thro IT.

Comment: @DanK, One of the fundamentals of UT is that, you should not write 2 tests for single functionality. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit-Testing delegating methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474057/unit-testing-delegating-methods)

Comment: @here2learn It's more of a loose recommendation than it is a hard-fast law. Your end goal is to test your code from a variety of perspectives and best practices is to keep your unit tests with the code it tests. But if you run into a situation where proper testing requires that you duplicate tests.. then duplicate your tests and don't lose any sleep over it.

Answer (score 0):

Unit test must test only one class. If you test interaction of more than one class instances so you're doing integration testing. You should consider using some mock library like jmock or mockito, the first one fit better for my uses.

If you use jmock you can do as above:

```
@Test
public void someTestMethod(){
 MyBusinessService instance = new MyBusinessService()

 Mockery context = new Mockery();
 ABCHandler mock1 = context.mock(ABCHandler.class); //creating a mock object

 instance.setABCHandler(mock1);

 context.checking(new Expectations(){{
  oneOf(mock1).do(); //creating a expectation wich expects exactly on call of method do.
 }});

 instance.doABC();

 context.assertIsSatisfied(); //check if the expectation is met

}
```

Comment: I think this definition of unit testing is far too restrictive. Where I work now we refer to unit testing as all testing done done by the programmer to verify that newly introduced code is sound. So that includes tests in a variety of classes. Integration testing on the other hand are the series of tests that run against the rest of the system (aka other programmer's unit tests) to verify that anything newly introduced didn't break functionality elsewhere.